# How to configure yii2 advance online hosting

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Please  I have a website I just finished developing using yii2 advance.
Please I will like to know how to arrange the files and folders so that if someone should type domain.com it will display d index page instead of have to rout to domin.com/frontend/web to view the page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: buddy add .htaccess file in frontend folder and root folder as given in link http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/755/how-to-hide-frontend-web-in-url-addresses-on-apache/

Comment: perfect, Thanks' buddy, i appreciate

Comment: but my error page is no longer working, what ever u type after the domin.com is accepted n move to index page

Comment: If u have any error then error action will work.